# ClickOnce Bootstrapper Packages

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, clickonce

I am using ClickOnce and I would like to add prerequisites to my applications.  The two I would like to add is Internet Explorer 9 and DirectX.

How can I do this?

Thanks,

Kevin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend requiring IE9 unless you are limiting your users to  those who have Windows 7 installed.

As far as requiring either application, you will need to create a custom prerequisite package.    For further information, see the answer to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173553/set-customactiondata-on-a-clickonce-setup-exe/6217485#6217485).